# Java question: Is there an integer or double version of the JLabel class?

Tags: java, programming-languages, user-interface, class

I am writing a gui program in Java. I found an example in my book on how to do the assignment, but it used JLabel which only takes strings and not numbers.

Comment: Convert the int or double to String before setting it as JLabel's text. See any of the `toString()` methods in [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) and [`Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html).

Answer (score 6):

There isn't, but you could make your own or adapt.

For example,

```
public class IntegerJLabel extends JLabel {

  public void setText(Integer num) {
    super.setText(Integer.toString(num));
  }

}
```

Or, as Adam Zalcman commented, you could just convert the int:

```
jLabel.setText(Integer.toString(25))
```

Either way, you're going to need to convert it yourself because there's no built-in integer version of JLabel.

Comment: Wrong function, it's is Integer.toString(25); http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29  The parseInt() takes a string and converts it to a number.  He wants a number to be converted to a string.  setText() takes a string.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: I think Integer.toString() is more readable than something like myInt + "", but I guess it is a matter of taste

Answer (score -2):

The JLabel class only takes A-Z, a-z and "_" "$". So you would need to make a new class.

Comment: Ferium - I believe you may be mistaken about this.  Have you tried it, to see what happens?

Comment: *woosh* and someone missed the sarcasm.